# Using IntersectionObserver to detect the video currently displayed on the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, intersection-observer

### What we want to achieve

I want to swipe a Video and switch the "id" part of the URL "https://xxxxxx/:id" to the ID of the currently displayed Video.

### Problems

I was able to achieve it with the following code, but when the video switches, the screen turns white for a moment.
How can I switch smoothly without turning white?

### Code

```
interface Content {
  id: string;
  videoUrl: string;
}

type Props = {
  content: Content;
  onIntersection?: (content: Content) => void;
};

const Content: React.FC<Props> = ({ content, onIntersection }) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting && onIntersection) {
          onIntersection(content);
        }
      },
      { threshold: 1 },
    );
    
    if (ref.current === null) return;
    observer.observe(ref.current);
    const { current } = ref;
    
    return () => {
      observer.unobserve(current);
    };
  });

  return (
    <video ref={ref} src={content.videoUrl} playsInline muted></video>
  );
};

const intersectCallback = (content: Content) => {
  navigate(content.id, { replace: false });
};

return (
  <>
    <div className="Contents">
      {(() => {
        return (
          contents.map(content => (
            <Content key={content.id} content={content} onIntersection={intersectCallback} />
          ))
        );
      })()}
    </div>
  </>
);
```

style.css

```
.Contents {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}
video {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

### Code(fixed version)

```
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        console.log(entry.target);
      }
    });
  }, { threshold: 0.5 });

  return (
    <div>
      {contents.map(c => <Content key={c.id} content={c} />)}
    </div>
  );

  const Content  = ({ content } : { content: Content }) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!ref.current) return;
      observer.observe(ref.current);

      return () => {
        observer.unobserve(ref.current!);
      };
    }, []);

    return (
      <video ref={ref} src={content.url} playsInline muted></video>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this happens because you create a new IntersectionObserver instance with every render. This is bad for performance.
Additionally, you do this in `useEffect` but also on the `Content` component: `onIntersection={intersectCallback}`. Are you sure you need to use both?

Comment: thank you.

I want to send the currently displayed Video Ref to the "intersectCallback".
As you answered, I don't know how to do it without using both.

Comment: If you update the state and use that in your Content component, doesn't that work?

Comment: Which state do you want to update? Sorry for being a beginner.

Comment: React dynamically re-renders parts of your JSX when a state property within it is changed. With state I mean [React's internal system](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) called the 'component state'. Specifically, for functional components you want to use [state hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: thank you! Fixed not creating a new IntersectionObserver instance for each render (see fix). Is it okay to write it like this?

Comment: Not entirely I think. You create an observer in the parent component (does this happen once or every render?), but observe it per each `Content` instance. This means that for every instance it checks all instances, if I'm not mistaken. This would mean that if `contents` has a length of 3, the observer will check 3x3 entries.